# Pandas values of a list are modified inplace inside a function / handling multilabels in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

What's the best way for **handling multilabels** in Pandas?

I stumbled into this weird behaviour:

- I want to append labels to a list, stored in a dataframe
- I made a function that should modify only a copy of the dataframe and return the modified dataframe
- In reality, that function seems to "modify" the original dataframe

#### Input

```py
def label(df):
    df = df.copy()
    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        new_entry = input(f'New label for {row.sentence}? -- ')
        row['labels_list'].append(new_entry)
        row['labels_str'] += new_entry
    return df

# Mock dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['sentence'] = ['X', 'Y', 'Y']
df['labels_list'] = [[], [], []]
df['labels_str'] = ''

# Behaviour
print('Before calling function, df is:')
print(df)
print()
print('Calling function on df, WITHOUT assigning the value returned to df:')
label(df)
print()
print('After calling function, df is:')
print(df)
```

#### Output

```py
Before calling function, df is:
  sentence labels_list labels_str
0        X          []           
1        Y          []           
2        Y          []           

Calling function on df, WITHOUT assigning the value returned to df:
New label for X? -- a
New label for Y? -- b
New label for Y? -- c

After calling function, df is:
  sentence labels_list labels_str
0        X         [a]           
1        Y         [b]           
2        Y         [c]
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the reason is that when you "store" objects (other than str, int, float...) inside a dataframe, **what is really stored is the address of the object**. So that even if you don't modify the dataframe 'in place', the old dataframe points to list objects that have been modified.

```py
def label(df):
    df = df.copy()
    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        new_entry = input(f'New label for {row.sentence}? -- ')
        row['labels_list'].append(new_entry)
        row['labels_str'] += new_entry
    return df

# Mock dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['sentence'] = ['X', 'Y', 'Y']
df['labels_list'] = [[], [], []]
df['labels_str'] = ''

# Behaviour
print('Before calling function, df is:')
print(df)
print()
print('Calling function on df, WITHOUT assigning the value returned to df:')
new_df = label(df)
print()
print('After calling function, df is:')
print(df)
print()
print('While new_df is:')
print(new_df)
```

#### Output

```
Before calling function, df is:
  sentence labels_list labels_str
0        X          []           
1        Y          []           
2        Y          []           

Calling function on df, WITHOUT assigning the value returned to df:
New label for X? -- a
New label for Y? -- b
New label for Y? -- c

After calling function, df is:
  sentence labels_list labels_str
0        X         [a]           
1        Y         [b]           
2        Y         [c]           

While new_df is:
  sentence labels_list labels_str
0        X         [a]          a
1        Y         [b]          b
2        Y         [c]          c
```